# dplyr get subset including date and two other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset

```
ID = c('A','A','B','B')
Date = as.Date(c('1990-01-01','1990-01-01','1990-02-01','1990-02-02'))
Condition1 = c(1,0,1,0)
Condition2 = c(0,1,0,1)
data1 <- data.frame(ID,Date,Condition1,Condition2)

ID     Date            Condition1     Condition2
A      1990-01-01          1              0
A      1990-01-01          0              1
B      1990-02-01          1              0
B      1990-02-02          0              1
```

How do I filter out the rows which the date with condition1 = 1 is equal to the date with condition2 = 1.
In this example, observations of A are filtered out.

Desired output:

```
ID     Date            Condition1     Condition2
B      1990-02-01          1              0
B      1990-02-02          0              1
```

My attempt:

```
    Filter1<- as.data.frame(data1 %>% group_by(ID) 
         %>% arrange(Date) %>% 
            filter(Date[Date[Condition1 ==1]] != Date[Condition2 ==1]))
```

And i got errors. is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: `filter` takes a logical input. You don't need to subset `Date` again - just `Date[Condition1 ==1]] != Date[Condition2 ==1]` should do it.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the Date but the output doesn't change. Weird.

Comment: `data1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Date[Condition1 ==1] != Date[Condition2 ==1])` works as per your example data.

Comment: Sorry. I typed wrong in my column name. It worked. lol

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion. I have to admit that this solution is not beautiful. It is only for reference.

```
ID = c('A','A','B','B')
Date = as.Date(c('1990-01-01','1990-01-01','1990-02-01','1990-02-02'))
Condition1 = c(1,0,1,0)
Condition2 = c(0,1,0,1)
data1 <- data.frame(ID,Date,Condition1,Condition2, stringsAsFactors =FALSE)

uniq=unique(data1$Date)

res=NULL
for ( idate in uniq)
{
  tmp=data1[data1$Date==idate,]
  res=rbind(res, tmp[!(nrow(tmp)>1 && tmp[1,'Condition1']==tmp[2,'Condition2']), ] )
}

res
```

The result is below:

```
  ID       Date Condition1 Condition2
3  B 1990-02-01          1          0
4  B 1990-02-02          0          1
```

Comment: The OP want to filter out the rows which the date with `condition1 = 1` is equal to the date with `condition2 = 1`. Where did you do that?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding as  I read the input and output